# How to filter a custom object list using java stream?

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I have the following object:

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName  = lastName;
        this.age       = age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

}
```

I get a `List` of `Person`

e.g.

1. First name: David, Last Name: Horn,  Age: 23
2. First name: Aaron, Last Name: Tomas, Age: 21
3. First name: John,  Last Name: Cook,  Age: 18
4. First name: James, Last Name: Polly, Age: 34
5. First name: Holly, Last Name: Lucas, Age: 15
6. First name: Maria, Last Name: Miles, Age: 28

I want to filter all the Persons whose **age** is **21 or above**.

Meaning, getting a new `List` with `Person` whose age is `>= 21`.

How do I do that with Java stream() ?

Comment: It's OK to post a question you're having trouble with and answer it by yourself when you didn't found anything in SO. It can be helpful for other developers facing the same issue. But in this case ... there must be a thousand posts on this subject

Comment: This looks like some study assignment. Please also post what you've tried. Where do you get stuck? Now you only posted the assignment details.

Answer (score 4):

If you have `List<Person>` and you want a `List<Person>` which are **21 and above**, you can write the following method:

```
public List<Person> filterPersonAbove21(List<Person> personList) {
    return personList.stream()
                     .filter(person -> person.getAge() >= 21)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The return value of `filterPersonAbove21` method contains a `List` of `Person` objects their age is 21 years and above.

e.g. regarding the last example:

1. First name: David, Last Name: Horn, Age: 23
2. First name: Aaron, Last Name: Tomas, Age: 21
3. First name: James, Last Name: Polly, Age: 34
4. First name: Maria, Last Name: Miles, Age: 28

Comment: shouldn't that be `person -> person.getAge() >= 21` ?

Comment: You are correct. :)